# this vs this@activity_main in context paramter for a function in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

when i create a toast in android studio I  got an error when  writing the code like this
but I searched online w and I found that when I replace "this" with "this@main_activity" which is the current activity my code works and compiles.
So what is the difference between "this" and "this@main_activity" ?

```
class MainActivity :AppCompat(){
val playbackListener = object  : YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener{
Toast.makeText(this, "Good, video is playing ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified -- you use the `@` qualifier when there are multiple definitions of `this` that you could access.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Toast.makeText()` call is inside of an object:

> ```
> object : YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {
>     Toast.makeText(this, "Good, video is playing ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
> }
> ```

Therefore, the value of `this` is the object (the PlaybackEventListener).

In order to refer to the instance of the `Activity` that your object lives inside, you can qualify the `this` keyword: `this@MainActivity`